# Google Hangouts Coversation Id

Tags: google-hangouts, google-chat

I'm trying to find a conversation id since I want to make a Google Hangouts/Chat bot but I can find it I remember it being there before in the Url but now its gone? I'm Using the 3rd party Hangups API

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `I remember it being there before` - where did you see it before? Bots need to be invited to rooms, you can't find an id and add your bot to it, if that is what you mean?

Comment: u see im not using a bot which you need a G suite account i am using a 3rd party library for HANGOUTS(even works on google chat) called hangups